# Minimal and maximal elements of $X= \mathbb{N} - \{1\}$ equipped with the divide relation

Tags: real-analysis

I'm stuck with the following question

> Consider $X= \mathbb{N} - \{1\}$ equipped with the divide relation ''$|$''. So, here $\forall m,n \in \mathbb{N} - \{1\}$, $n\leq m \Leftrightarrow n\left| m \right. \Leftrightarrow \exists k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m=kn$.
>
> Show that the minimal elements of $X$ are the prime numbers and $X$ has no maximal elements.

How exactly can I "show" this?
Does $X$ only consist of $X= \left\{ {2,4,6,8,...} \right\} $, since it is equipped with the divide relation? I might be misunderstanding what $X$ looks like.

Comment: What makes you think that $X=\{2,4,6,8,\dots\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what $X$ looks like. $X$ is just the set of all natural numbers except for $1$, so $X=\{2,3,4,5,...\}$.

Now as how to prove the statement, think about what it means to be a minimal element. $x\in X$ is minimal if there exists no $y\in X$, $y\neq x$, such that $y\leq x$, i.e. $y|x$. Why are these the prime numbers? Same with the fact there are no maximal elements, show that there is no $x\in X$ such that there is no $y\in X$, $y\neq x$ which satisfies $x\leq y$, i.e. $x|y$.

I hope this helps you with finding a proof.

Comment: What is confusing me, is that I'm used to finding only one minimal element, not more than one.

Comment: That is probably because you are used to linear orders, like on $\mathbb{N},\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$. But there are a lot of non-linear orders like division or subset. There having multiple minimal elements is far more likely.

Answer (score 0):

The sitution is much different for the natural numbers including zero. 
Then the smallest element is $1$ and the largest element is $0$. Note the difference between smallest and minimal element as well es largest and maximal element.

In your case, the primes are the minimal elements since no prime divides the other (so they are not comparable) and each number is divided by prime (so they are minimal). There is no maximal element since the set you are considering is not bound from above.